# Existence of fixed point implies completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $f: X \to X$ be a map such that there exists $C \in [0,1/2)$ and satisfy $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq C[d(x,f(x))+d(y,f(y))]$ for all $x,y \in X$.

I want to prove that if $f$ has a fixed point then $X$ is complete.

Comment: some $f$ or any $f$?

Comment: for every $f$ satisfying this condition

Comment: i.e. every map of this kind has a fixed point

Comment: Not clear for me what you want to prove: If every $f$ satisfyinfg this condition has an extreme point then $X$ is complete? or if some $f$ satisfies this and has an extreme point then $X$ is complete?

Comment: if every $f$ satisfying this condition has a fixed point then $X$ is complete.